# When is Bleach: Can’t Fear Your Own World set?

Tags: bleach

i got an email from Viz Media talking about a [a new *Bleach* novel](https://www.viz.com/read/novel/bleach-can-t-fear-your-own-world-volume-1/product/6339/paperback?utm_source=Iterable&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Pub_Releases_07-02-2020). the description in the email says

> **Bleach: Can’t Fear Your Own World, Vol. 1 (Novel)**

> Go deeper into the world of Bleach with the novels!

> The Quincies’s Thousand Year Blood War is over, but the embers of turmoil still smolder in the Soul Society. Tokinada Tsunayashiro, elevated to head of his clan after a slew of assassinations take out every other claimant to the title, has a grand plan to create a new Soul King. His dark ambitions soon sow the seeds of a new total war across the realms, but all is not lost. There is one unlikely Soul Reaper who holds the key to defusing the conflict—Shuhei Hisagi, assistant captain of the Ninth Company and reporter for the Seireitei Bulletin!

reading this, it made me think of *The Last: Naruto the Movie* where it was released after the manga's end and set after the major plot but before the final chapter where we saw Boruto.

so i started to wonder if this novel is set after the end of the manga, or if like the Naruto Movie it is after the major plot (Thousand Year Blood War) but before we saw Ichigo's and Rukia's kids in the final chapter.

So when is *Bleach: Can’t Fear Your Own World* set?

NOTE: as of posting this question the link says the book is on pre-order to be released on July 7th, however as Official English Translations tend to lag behind the original japanese versions i am making the assumption that the novel is already released in japan

Answer (score -1):

Can't Fear Your Own World is set months after the Thousand Year Blood War arc and is set before 9 years before the epilogue.

Comment: Welcome to Anime.SE! Do you have a source for this?

Comment: Hi @TheRinnegan, welcome to Anime & Manga. Do you have a source for your answer? If so, please [edit] your answer to include it; see ‘[How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer)’ for useful guidelines on posting answers here. Also, do take our [tour]!